# Windows Azure Storage from the Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure-storage

I'm trying to use Azure Blob Storage from my Windows Phone for a Proof of Concept. I installed the NuGet package [phone.storage](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Phone.Storage) and followed the code samples. When trying to store a blob though I get an error message:

> Server failed to authenticate the request.
>   Make sure the value of
>   Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
>   RequestId:aed05ab4-8ff0-4362-b49e-94a442c1e68b
>   Time:2012-07-20T15:25:32.3047397Z

The error message time is 1 hour behind from my PC time - I'm based in the UK where we are currently on British Summer Time (GMT+1) so am wondering if this is an issue? Although when I use the standard Windows Azure Storage Package in a console app I can store blobs fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem!

To fix change your `region` and `language`, I had to change my region from United States.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you're using the phone emulator, and it has some sort of BST bug? Is that guess possible? (Does it work if you deploy to the actual phone rather than the emulator?)

Comment: I get the same issue when running on my phone too unfortunately

Comment: So much for my guess then. It's probably just that the time is reported in GMT, which happens to be one hour off of your local time. Red herring, I'd say.